# Can a Jenkins build access the archived artifacts from itself?

Tags: jenkins

I'm using Jenkins and have the "Archive the Artifacts" step at the end of my builds to archive them into a zip file.

Instead of using this step, I'd like to use a script to push the artifacts to a remote server at the end of the build. The server I'm pushing to uses a REST API / HTTP PUT request in a script to upload files.

Note that I'm looking to access the artifact created in the same build. So if I'm on build #5, I want the artifacts from build #5, not build #4.

Is there any way to access this zip file with a script, in the same build that it was created in?

I need to upload this zip remotely and don't want to create another job to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way that I have found to access the "Archive the Artifacts" package of the build that generates it. This step always occurs last in the build. Accessing the URL prior to the build ending (during the build via script for example) results in a blank zip file. To get around this limitation, I'm making a second linked build job to grab the zip and run my script to deploy it.

Answer (score 5):

You can install one of the "[Publish Over...](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Publish+Over+...)" plugins to upload your artifacts at the end of a build.

> The goal of the Publish Over plugins is to provide a consistent set of
>   features and behaviours when sending build artifacts ... somewhere.

See also the [full list of "upload" plugins](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/label/JENKINS/plugin-upload) for other methods of publishing your artifacts.

Comment: I'm using a cURL script to verify on the command line I can upload my artifacts. I may end up having to make this a separate job that kicks off to just do the deploy. Is there any way to use the Publish Over plugins to package artifacts into the zip and then run my script?

Comment: Packaging things probably isn't within the scope of these plugins. You can, however, create the zip file as the last build step of your job.

Comment: It looks like I can grab the zip file as the last step, but it ends up being blank. This makes sense as "Archive the Artifacts" is running last in the build. I can't find any way to run a script in the Publish Over plugins so I think I need to create a separate job.

Comment: The files you want to upload are created (or otherwise exist) during your build, so I meant that you can just add an extra build step which creates a zip file from these. Then upload *that* file with the "Publish Over" plugin.

Answer (score 5):

Like @Christopher said, you can use any of the `Publish Over` plugins on the Jenkins Plugins page to upload the artifact to any of the

If you want to access the archived zip file from within the build itself, you can use the following link to access it:

`http://<server>/job/${JOB_NAME}/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/<artifact name w/folder>`

For example:

- server  = `myserver.com`
- job name = `myproject`
- artifact = `del/project.zip`

Your URL would be:

`http://myserver.com/job/myproject/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/del/project.zip`

EDIT: Question was changed. In any case, this would work for accessing the artifact of the previous build in the current one.

Comment: But that URL would be accessing the artifacts of the *last* build, not the current one. Hence my suggestion to use a publisher plugin at the end of the build.

Comment: True. However, he specified he is using "Archive the Artifacts", which is usually the last step in a build - hence my suggestion. I figured he needs to access the existing artifact every build.

Comment: Christopher is correct, I need to access the artifacts from the build they were created in.

Comment: Aah ok. In that case, my answer is invalid. Editing.

Comment: You can using JOB_URL variables. This is easier.